# PHPMailer not working with complications

Tags: php, phpmailer

This is very weird.

I'm using PHPMailer on a Godaddy shared host. I have one file in the root of my site, `mail.php` that contains this:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->Host       = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
    $mail->Port       = 25;                   
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 4;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "none";                 
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = false;
    $mail->Username   = "";
    $mail->Password   = "";

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('to@example.com', 'Recipient');


    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

This works fine. However, when I tried making it a bit more complicated, it doesn't work. I tried using (mostly) the same code in a subdirectory, `/register/index.php`. It contains this:

```
session_start();

  error_reporting(E_ALL);

 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '../PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
require '../PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '../PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
//Server settings
$mail->Host       = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
$mail->Port       = 25;                   
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "none";                 
$mail->SMTPAuth   = false;
$mail->Username   = "";
$mail->Password   = "";    


      $admin_email = "
      <div id='wrapper' style='background: #eee;padding: 30px 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;'>
      <div id='admin-email' style='display: block; padding: 30px; width: 700px; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 100%; background: #fff;'>
        <h1 style='font-weight: 500;padding: 32px 16px; margin: -30px; margin-bottom: 20px; font-size: 36px; background: #1c5d99;color: #fff; text-align: center;'>
          My Business
        </h1>
        <h1 style='font-weight: 400; font-size: 28px;margin-bottom: 32px;text-align: center;'>
          New Registration
        </h1>
        <p>You've received a new registration from {$f_name} {$m_name} {$l_name}.</p>
        <p><b>User Info:</b></p>
        <p><b>Name:</b> {$f_name} {$m_name} {$l_name}</p>
        <p><b>Email:</b> {$email}</p>
        <p><b>Phone:</b> {$phone}</p>
        <p><b>Username:</b> {$username}</p>
        <p><b>Found us by:</b> {$how_found}</b></p>
        <p><b>About:</b> {$about}</p>
        <p><b>Whatsapp Groups?</b> {$whatsapp}</p>
        <hr>
        <p>
          <a href='http://{$domainname}/admin/controller.php?action=approveUser&userId={$user_id}' style='background: #eee; border-radius: 2px; text-decoration: none; background: #0a0; color: #fff; display: inline-block; padding: 8px 16px; border: 1px solid rbga(0,0,0,.4);'>Approve User</a>
          <a href='http://{$domainname}/admin/controller.php?action=rejectUser&userId={$user_id}' style='background: #eee; border-radius: 2px; text-decoration: none; background: #c00; color: #fff; display: inline-block; padding: 8px 16px; border: 1px solid rbga(0,0,0,.4);'>Reject User</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      ";

      $name = "{$f_name} {$m_name} {$l_name}";

      //Recipients
      $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
      $mail->addAddress("to@example.com", $name);


      //Content
      $mail->isHTML(true);                 
      $mail->Subject = 'New Registration';
      $mail->Body    = $admin_email;

      echo $mail->Body;

      $mail->send();

      echo "<pre>";
      var_dump($mail);
      echo "</pre>";

      die();

      die("success");
    }
  }
```

This doesn't send emails at all. I can't figure out why this isn't working. Is it because of something else I haven't seen? There are no errors as far as I can tell. Why isn't this working?

Comment: turn on error checking .. `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`

Comment: `$mail->ErrorInfo` will tell you the problem. Not really sure why you removed the `try` / `catch` supporting that.

Comment: In the `var_dump` `ErrorInfo` is empty. @smith, I tried that, no errors.

Comment: I removed the `try/catch` because there is code between the first block and the second (you can tell by the different indentation)

Comment: `}
  }` why are those still part of the code then, at the end of the 2nd code block?

Comment: that's part of other code that's not relevant (`if/else` blocks)

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` that I doubt does very much unless it's being logged. Try to display them `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Nope, still nothing.

Comment: I've also seen on the rare occasion where full HTML markup was required. I remember answering a question like this a few years ago, if my memory serves me right.

Comment: What would that require?

Comment: ... this `<!DOCTYPE><html><head></head><body> Your HTML here </body></html>`

Comment: also try to include `$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';` as you did for the other one.

Comment: have you try the primitive mail function to test out if the service is running correctly?

Comment: Why would you choose to remove all your error checking code, when it’s exactly the thing that will tell you what’s going wrong?